# Execute shell command from groovy w/out timeout

Tags: groovy

In groovy, you can execute a shell command like so:

```
def process = "<some shell command>".execute()
println process.text()
```

But if the command is a long running command, I find that it times out. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: even if with `process.waitFor()` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do some long running stufff (45 min+) doing this where I build up a cmdLine object that is the command line to run and then:

```
def fose = new FileOutputStream(logFileErr)
def foss = new FileOutputStream(logFileStd)
Process proc = cmdLine.execute()
fose << proc.in
fose << proc.err
foss << proc.out
proc.waitFor()
```

It's been working for me a couple of years now (to the point I haven't had to revisit this solution)